# APACHE zeppelin JSP support not found

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have a error relative to a JSP 
support not found

log:

> INFO [2016-03-11 11:01:26,017] ({main} StdSchedulerFactory.java[instantiate]:1339) - Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
>    INFO [2016-03-11 11:01:26,018] ({main} StdSchedulerFactory.java[instantiate]:1343) - Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.1
>    INFO [2016-03-11 11:01:26,019] ({main} QuartzScheduler.java[start]:575) - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
>    INFO [2016-03-11 11:01:26,173] ({main} Notebook.java[]:107) - Notebook indexing started...
>    INFO [2016-03-11 11:01:26,299] ({main} LuceneSearch.java[addIndexDocs]:285) - Indexing 0 notebooks took 125ms
>    INFO [2016-03-11 11:01:26,313] ({main} Notebook.java[]:109) - Notebook indexing finished: 0 indexed in 0s
>    INFO [2016-03-11 11:01:27,225] ({main} ServerImpl.java[initDestination]:94) - Setting the server's publish address to be /
>    INFO [2016-03-11 11:01:28,112] ({main} StandardDescriptorProcessor.java[visitServlet]:284) - NO JSP Support for /srv/zeppelin/tmp/webapp, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
>    INFO [2016-03-11 11:01:31,655] ({main} AbstractConnector.java[doStart]:338) - Started SelectChannelConnector@192.168.1.105:8090
>    INFO [2016-03-11 11:01:31,677] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[main]:115) - Done, zeppelin server started

zeppelin-site.xml

> 

```
<configuration>
<property>
 <name>zeppelin.server.addr</name>
 <value>192.168.1.105</value>
  <description>Server address</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.server.port</name>
  <value>8090</value>
  <description>Server port.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.server.context.path</name>
  <value>/srv/zeppelin/tmp/webapp</value>
  <description>Context Path of the Web Application</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.war.tempdir</name>
  <value>/srv/zeppelin/tmp</value>
  <description>Location of jetty temporary directory</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.notebook.dir</name>
  <value>/srv/zeppelin/notebook</value>
  <description>path or URI for notebook persist</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.notebook.homescreen</name>
  <value></value>
  <description>id of notebook to be displayed in homescreen. ex) 2A94M5J1Z Empty value displays default home screen</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.notebook.homescreen.hide</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>hide homescreen notebook from list when this value set to true</description>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem....

```
<property>
  <name>zeppelin.server.context.path</name>
  <value>/</value>
  <description>Context Path of the Web Application</description>
</property>
```

i think you have to put the root path and somewhere in the filesystem the software find the jsp support